# Canvas2Image not working in IE11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, html5-canvas, internet-explorer-11, html2canvas

Canvas2Image giving error in IE11. I am getting an error as

> Object doesn't support this action

in Canvas2Image.js at line

```
var event = new MouseEvent('click',{"bubbles":false, "cancelable":false});
```

Answer (score 0):

I.E has problem with MouseEvents in some cases.

as a work around you could use something like below

```
var event = document.createEvent("MouseEvent");
event.initMouseEvent("click",false,false,window,0,0,0,0,0,false,false,false,false,0,null);
```

so your logic with fallback IE logic would be like below.

```
if (typeof MouseEvent !== 'function') {
    var event = document.createEvent("MouseEvent");
    event.initMouseEvent("click", false, false, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
} else {
    var event = new MouseEvent('click',{"bubbles":false, "cancelable":false});
}
```

Comment: So after adding above code i dont see any error in the console. But after that nothing is happening.

Comment: @chetnagupta did you forget to put final function? I don't see anything code.

Comment: function saveFile (strData,filename) {
        var save_link = document.createElement('a');
        save_link.href = strData;
        save_link.download = filename;
        if (typeof MouseEvent !== 'function') {
            var event = document.createEvent("MouseEvent");
            event.initMouseEvent("click", false, false, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
            save_link.dispatchEvent(event);
        } else {
            var event = new MouseEvent('click',{"bubbles":false, "cancelable":false});
            save_link.dispatchEvent(event);       }}

Comment: Looks like Canvas2ImageJS doesnt work in IE11 at all. i cant find any working demo in IE11 for the same.

Answer (score 0):

finally, I found solution in this link.

(I could success in IE11. 
using with html2canvas.js v0.41(old version) )

https://phpschool.com/gnuboard4/bbs/board.php?bo_table=tipntech&wr_id=79712&sca=&sfl=wr_subject%7C%7Cwr_content&stx=%BF%DC%BA%CE+%C0%CC%B9%CC%C1%F6&sop=and

[image]

Comment: Does the download work in IE with html2canvas.js v0.41 ?? looks like it still doenst work for me

Comment: Download happens in IE but the graphs disappear.Only text available is captured in the screenshot and we see white patches in place of charts/graphs